# EXCEL Formula to find and copy cell based on criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I have two tables, one which contains the pricing increase for a product and the other with the full code of the product. In my sample you will notice in column B the base size and column C containing the increase. I would like to use each item in column E to search in Column B and find the matching partial size and then copy the increase to column F.
I have manually input how it would look but require a formula as there are hundreds of sizes.
[SampleData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tfJ2.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the codes aren't perfectly matching across the tables. For example, you've matched product 3024C in the left table with products 3024C4 and 3024C3 in the right table. Unless there is some logic to the number suffixes, it will be hard to match.

If the product codes match perfectly across the two tables, the formula you'd put in column F1 (where 0.56 is now) would be:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E1,A:A,0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How it works is  3024c gives me the size of the product and the part after that gives me how many colors B means black for example. So a 3024C4 is a product 30" x 24" and it has 4 colors on it. A 3024BC2 would be 30" x 24" made from Black material with 2 colors. When applying a price increase I have formulas that work on the left side table and the increase only applies to the raw material, therefore I do not need all of the other information at that point.

Comment: So what I am trying to do is if the code in the right table includes any of the items from the left table then place that code adjacent to the code in the right table.  EG there are 15 combinations using 3024C and another 8 combinations using 3024ASC. The 3024 size is then followed by another 60 Sizes and about 20 combinations of colors that could apply to each size and that is why I am trying to automate it. Thanks

Comment: In that case, you would need to have a mapping table so you can associate each of the product + colour combinations from the right table to the base product that would be found on the left table. Once you have the base product in the right table, you can then match it to the left table to find the price of that product.